# Multilevel Complex form with formtastic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I have a scenario which needs a very complex form, and i need help in it.

I have three tables

```
create_table "permissions", :force => true do |t|
    t.boolean  "can_read"
    t.boolean  "can_create"
    t.boolean  "can_edit"
    t.boolean  "can_delete"
    t.integer  "role_id"
    t.integer  "resource_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

create_table "resources", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "class_name"
    t.string   "class_action"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "parent_resource"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

create_table "roles", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

with the models and associations

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, :through => :user_roles
  has_many :permissions

  def to_s
    self.name
  end
end

class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Resource", :foreign_key => "parent_resource"

  scope :root, lambda {
    {
      :conditions => "parent_resource IS NULL"
    }
  }
end

class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :resource
end
```

Suppose we have 2 roles, admin, user,  this time, i need a form structure like the image in the [this link](http://picasaweb.google.com/nazarhussain/GeneralPublic?authkey=Gv1sRgCKavn7a6nOShVA#5548818215262471810)

How can i make this form? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I created a gem that makes it easier to handle nested forms inside formtastic: [formtastic_cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/formtastic-cocoon).

That should get you started.

Comment: From which source i have to install this gem. I used bundle install, but it does not available.

Comment: Did this work for you? You should add `gem 'formtastic_cocoon'` to your `Gemfile`, and then run `bundle install`. Is the description on the github page clear enough for you?